# Are larger objects slower to copy (C++)?

Tags: c++, performance, memory

If you want to copy an object (on the stack) in C++, is it slower to copy larger objects? Are objects instantly copied, or are the bytes of the data copied in an iterative way?:

```
class Small {
public:
    int stuff[32];
};

class Big {
public:
    int stuff[1024];
};

...

Small small;
Big big;

Small small2 = Small(small); //Faster?
Big big2 = Big(big); //Slower?
```

Sorry but at the moment I have no time to test this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, larger objects take more time to copy or move than smaller object.

An array of 32 integers takes 32 operations to copy or move.
An array of 1024 integers takes 1024 operations to copy or move.

The question is whether or not the time difference is significant.  With modern processors, most copy operations are on the order of nanoseconds.  So, is (approximately) 1000 more nanoseconds going to affect your program?  It depends.  If your program spends milliseconds or more waiting for I/O, the difference may not be significant.

**Edit 1:**
The amount of space required may be more significant that the time spent copying.

The general rule of thumb with large objects is to let them sit and pass pointers to the object; refrain from copying or moving the large objects.  Pointers take less room and are faster to copy and move than large objects.  Also prefer references to pointers.

**Edit 2: - The Stack**
Copying onto the *stack* depends on the processor and the compiler's protocol.  Stacks are not required.

On a classic implementation that uses stacks for passing parameters and local variable allocation, the overhead, in addition to copying the objects, involves incrementing a stack pointer variable.

So, if I pass 32 integers to a function, there will be 32 copy operations plus an addition operation to the stack pointer.

In general, the concern of stack space is more important that the time required to push (copy) the large object onto the stack.

Your compiler may be able to pass your object by pointer depending on the optimization level and other attributes.

Comment: wouldn't an array of 32 integers take 128 operations and 1024 take 4096 operations?

Comment: `With modern processors, most copy operations are on the order of nanoseconds` before copying or moving anything, chances are that you still have to allocate the memory that you need and this operation is a source of slowness and your CPU can't do too much about it; you can have a super fast CPU and a slow `malloc`, and in this case you get a slow program .

Comment: @name "operation" is just used as a generic term here I think, not a concrete unit such as clock cycle.

Comment: Depends on the architecture of your system.  An ARM7 processor can copy 32 bytes in one operation.  So one integer takes one operation.

Comment: @user2485710 The question asks about stack in particular.

Comment: "Operation" in this context depends on the processor, as well as the bitsize of an integer.  A 16-bit processor would take more operations to copy a 32-bit integer than a 32-bit or 64-bit processor.

Comment: @NeilKirk I don't know who wants to allocate an array of `1024` elements on the stack, even stranger is to copy said object ( just why ? ), but okay, I was going to assume that this was about dynamic memory .

Comment: @user2485710 I think you have to bare in mind that the question is just a generic example.

Comment: @user2485710 Well, I was sitting here thinking and got curious, so I decided to post it on SO. I mean, its always good to know anyways.

Comment: You might mention the as-if rule and copy-ellision, which might mean that the bigger one is faster in the end ;-).

Comment: The "or move" here is deceiving at best, and outright false in at least some cases. Just for an obvious example, consider a string that implements short string optimization. When moving a long string (one that doesn't fit in the SSO buffer) moving the string object will typically require copying around 3 objects, even though the string object itself might contain (for example) 32.

Answer (score 2):

It is not that LARGER objects take longer to copy but rather the processing required to do the copying.

Yes, copying

```
    char [4096] ;
```

generally takes longer than copying

```
    char [32] ;
```

However, there are other things that can take even longer. If you copy constructor and assignment operators do a lot of other processing, that can often be much more computationally intensive than moving data around.

Coping an array of 32 integers does not necessarily mean 32 instructions. Some processors have block move instructions. However, one block move instructions can take multiple cycles to execute.

Answer (score 1):

The more bytes that need to be copied the longer it will take. Whether this is significant to your overall performance is a different matter. The real killer is when copies require dynamic memory allocations. A straight copy of bytes is usually not that bad, whether on the stack or heap (so long as the destination memory is already allocated). Be careful putting large arrays on the stack.

Comment: I generally don't use the stack at all except for temporary values, the rest stays on the heap

Comment: @name Stack is good for local variables, if that's what you mean by temporary values, as it's faster than heap.

Comment: Yep, I try to keep heap allocations low, and by temporary values I did mean local variables.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, though obviously a larger object means more data has to move and therefore takes longer there are cases were the overhead of copying matters more...

eg.

```
Big b1;
Big b2 = b1;
```

will be fast, stack to stack copies are really quick to allocate the memory and the copy is just a set of fast CPU instructions to copy the data, usually in an optimized burst of specialized instructions.

```
Small s1;
Small* s2 = new Small(s1);
```

this might not be quite as fast, you have to allocate memory on the heap which is relatively expensive, and then copy the data. Obviously there will be a point at which the memory copy plus allocation is cheaper than the previous example, if the Big object is really big (and I couldn't tell you what that point is, it depends on heap fragmentation, heap implementation - a pool will be quicker, and the time taken to perform the stack copy).

Then there's the copy-construction aspect of this, you may have a single byte array in your
object, but most objects have more member variables, and a copy ctor to deal with each one individually, some even having specialized routines that are required to perform the copy, such as log the copying or lock some shared resource that cannot be accessed in parallel.